# When execute code below I receive the message error str concatenate

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

Hy guys! I started learn programming. And when execute code below I receive the message error str concatenate.

```
import random

word_list = ["ababababababab", "baloon", "banana"]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

print(chosen_word)

guess = input("Guess the word, type one letter: \n").lower()

i = 0
while (i < len(chosen_word)):
    for i in chosen_word:
        if i == guess:
            print(guess)
    i += 1
```

The message error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: In `i += 1`, `i` is a string because of `for i in chosen_word`. You should use two different variable names.

Comment: Or rather, use only *one* variable and *one* loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
j = ""
for j in chosen_word:
    if j == guess:
        print(guess)
```

Use one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, put input in a while loop (why did you do while condition in parenthesis?). Another thing that I've changes is to use **if** statement insted **for** loop.

```
import random

word_list = ["ababababababab", "baloon", "banana"]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

print(chosen_word)

i = 0
while i < len(chosen_word):
    guess = input("Guess the word, type one letter: \n").lower()
    if guess in chosen_word:
        print(f'Yep {guess} is in a word')
    i += 1
```